# Create custom hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create a custom query,
but my select returns empty results.

```
this.getSession()
.createQuery("FROM com.dummy.tralala.MyClass AS test where test.name in (:labels)")
.setParameter("labels",myLabels).list()
;
```

what is wrong?

when I do it like this

```
.createQuery("FROM com.dummy.tralala.MyClass AS test where test.name in ("+myLabelsString+")").list()
```

then it is working just fine.

Comment: Is "myLabels" a List? I think that with a List it should work fine.

Comment: labels is a string = " 'a', 'b'", should that be a List?

Comment: @TanTan yes, it should.

Comment: now I have java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: and what if I use setString instedOf Parameter and then put String of labels?

Comment: post your method where that query is being created, also where is the classCastException occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a list of parameters, use the method *setParameterList*

```
this.getSession()
                .createQuery("FROM com.dummy.tralala.MyClass AS settings where settings.name in (:labels)")
                .setParameterList("labels",myLabels).list();
```

*myLabels* could be a Collection or an array.

Comment: yes, I tried that and it worked perfectly. Thanks :)